# Как сделать параметры в функции JavaScript необязательными?

Tags: javascript, функции, rest, url, request

У меня есть `REST`-метод фильтра товаров(интернет-магазина) на `back-end`. Метод работает таким образом, что при желании ему можно передавать не все входные параметры(`reuired` = `false`). То есть можно передать только максимальную цену, без минимальной и он отработает. Соответственно, для `front-end`'а мне нужно составить ссылку на `JavaScript`, чтобы отправить запрос. Для этого мне нужно в ссылке прописать переменные, которые получаю через входные параметры функции. Как я могу составить ссылку, не используя некоторые параметры.

```js
function createTeaCardsFilter(number = '0', sortingParams = 'NAME_INCREASE', colorId, typeId, countryId, min, max,) {

    var urlFilter = new URL("http://localhost:8080/tea/filter?" + 'page=' + number + "&sortingParams=" + sortingParams + '&colorId=' + colorId + '&countryId=' + countryId + '&typeId=' + typeId + '&min=' + min + '&max' + max);


    const xhrFilt = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhrFilt.open('GET', urlFilter)

    xhrFilt.send()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [деструктуризацию](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#umnye-parametry-funktsiy).

Пример применения деструктуризации:

```js
function foo({
  a,
  b,
  c
}) {
  console.log(arguments);
}

const settings = {
  a: 'a',
  c: 'abc'
}

foo(settings);
```

Как мы видим, в консоль выводятся только переданные параметры.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function composeURLSearchParams(o) {
  return Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, key) => {
    const val = o[key];
    if (val !== undefined && val !== null && val !== '') {
      acc.append(key, val);
    }
    return acc;
  }, new URLSearchParams({}));
}

function createTeaCardsFilter(number = '0', sortingParams = 'NAME_INCREASE', colorId, typeId, countryId, min, max) {
  const urlSearchParams = composeURLSearchParams({
    number,
    sortingParams,
    colorId,
    typeId,
    countryId,
    min,
    max
  });

  const urlFilter = new URL("http://localhost:8080/tea/filter");
  urlFilter.search = urlSearchParams;

  console.log(urlFilter.toString());
}

// усовершенствованный вариант
function createTeaCardsFilter2(param) {
  const urlSearchParams = composeURLSearchParams({
    number: '0', sortingParams: 'NAME_INCREASE',
    ...param
  });

  const urlFilter = new URL("http://localhost:8080/tea/filter");
  urlFilter.search = urlSearchParams;

  console.log(urlFilter.toString());
}

createTeaCardsFilter();
createTeaCardsFilter2({colorId: 1});
```

Возможно будет удобнее заменить список аргументов функции `createTeaCardsFilter` на 1 аргумент и вызывать функцию так `createTeaCardsFilter({colorId: 1})`. В качестве примера дописал функцию `createTeaCardsFilter2`.